# How to refactor a long method in ruby

Tags: ruby, coding-style

Below is an example of my coding style. Sometimes I end up with 50 line methods.

```
def make_juice
  wash_fruits()
  cut_fruits()

  while(true) do
    if electicity_available?
      turn_on_lights()
      break
    else
      pay_electricity_bill()
      sleep(60)
    end
  end

  mix_fruits_in_mixer()
  add_sugar()
end

# ---------- function definitions ----------

def wash_fruits
  # ...
end
def cut_fruits
  # ...
end
def electricity_avalable?
  # return true  if available
end
def turn_on_lights
  # turn on 
end
def pay_electricity_bill
  # pay
end
def create_juice
  # steps for creating juice
end
def add_sugar
  # steps for adding sugar
end
```

It is not ruby convention to write long methods, and I would like to know the standard way of refactoring a ruby program. I tried to refactor the code and got the result below:

```
def wash_fruits
  # ...
  cut_fruits
end

def cut_fruits
  # ...
  turn_on_lights
end

def turn_on_lights
  while(true) do
    if electricity_avalable?
      turn_on_lights
      break
    else
      sleep 1.hour
    end
  end
  mix_fruits_in_mixer
end

def mix_fruits_in_mixer
  # ...
  add_sugar
end

def turn_on_lights
  # ...
end

def add_sugar
  # ...
  # ... program exits
end
```

The method names in the second style isn't very meaningful. Is this the right way to refactor a program?

Comment: Opinion questions, as you alluded to, are generally frowned upon here. You may want to check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Josh, I agree with your advice, but more because the OP has presented working code. SO is concerned with broken code and "how to" questions, whereas Code Review seeks to show how working code can be improved.

Comment: It does not make sense to post the code before you refactor attempt. You think it is worse than the refactored code; why do you want to show that to us? You don't need to ask about refactoring. Just post you best attempt, and ask whether that is good code. Refactoring will follow from that.

Comment: You tell the program (or robot?) to make juice and it may end up in a dark kitchen paying bills – that doesn't sound right to me. Wouldn't it make more sense to fail if something goes wrong?

Comment: @Stefan is absolutely right, and that's the crux of the matter. Often, long methods are a sign that you're violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). In this case, it's easy to spot. Nobody would expect paying bills to be part of a juice-making procedure. In real-world scenarios it can be tricky but if you recognize the refactoring pattern you can improve the code. Recommended books: Refactoring (Ruby Edition), and Sandi Metz's books.

Comment: @MarkThomas Absolutely not! This question would get closed at Code Review for being example code. It isn't doing anything. Please take a look at their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before making such recommendations again.

Comment: @JoshBrody Same goes for you ^^

Comment: @Mast, you are correct. I suppose it's like this: Broken code: http://stackoverflow.com; Working code: http://CodeReview.stackexchange.com; Hypothetical code: http://SoftwareEngineering.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @MarkThomas Roughly, yes. But take a look at each help center to notice not everything under those categories is automatically allowed.

Comment: @MarkThomas Thank you for the book recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to write the following<sup>1</sup>.

```
def make_juice
  wash_fruits
  cut_fruits
  turn_on_lights
  mix_fruits_in_mixer
  add_sugar
end

def turn_on_lights
  until electricity_available?
    pay_electricity_bill()
    sleep(60)
  end
  flip_switch_on
end
```

<sup>1 The logic suggests that washing and cutting might be done in the dark and one might have to pay the electricity bill multiple times to get power back. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯</sup>.